# Transform rows into columns in sql server wrong result

Tags: mysql, transform

I have table:

```
ID  platform
1   IOS
2   Android
3   Windows
4   IOS
5   IOS
6   IOS
7   IOS
8   Windows
9   Windows
10  Android
```

I want to get for platform = 'Android' and platform = 'IOS' the number of appearance. 
This i did by:

```
select  top 2  platform, max(platformNumber) as count
from(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by platform order by platform ) as platformNumber, B.* from B) temp 
group by platform
```

The result I am getting:

```
platform count
Android 2
IOS 5
```

Now i want to be able to transform the columns to show:

```
IOS Android 
5     2
```

For this i tried this script:

```
select platform,  'platform' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by platform order by platform ) as varchar(10)) columnsqu
from
(
select  top 2  platform, max(platformNumber) as count
from(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by platform order by platform ) as platformNumber, B.* from B) temp 
group by platform) Temp2
PIVOT
(
MAX(count) FOR columnsqu IN (IOS,Android)
)PIV
```

I am getting error...

Comment: I'm not completely up-to-date, but I don't think row_number is a mysql construct

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a pivot query here:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN platform = 'IOS' THEN 1 END) AS IOS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN platform = 'Android' THEN 1 END) AS Android
FROM B
WHERE
    platform IN ('IOS', 'Android')
GROUP BY
    platform;
```